# Проблема с постраничной навигацией

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема с постраничной навигацией. Есть раздел с книгами, в этом разделе выводятся книги которые ещё не были куплены. Существует два массива: my_books и shop_books. Массив шопбукс выбирает по 10 рядов с базы (по постраничной навигацией). После этого идёт перебор shop_books и из него удаляются книги которые в массиве my_books. Но проблема в том, что выборки идёт по 10 книг, а потом из них удаляются купленные, то есть на станице должно выводится по 10 книг, а выводится по 7-5( так как из массива удаляются книги) Вопрос вот в чём, как сделать чтобы из конечного профильтрованного массива сделать выборку по 10 книг?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `books` $sql ORDER BY `level` ASC LIMIT ".$begin0.", ".$pnumber0) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

 $shop_books[$row['id']] = array("id"=>$row['id'],"name"=>$row['name'],"type"=>$row['type'],"price"=>$row['price'],"price_type"=>$row['price_type'],"level"=>$row['level'],"technique"=>$row['technique']);
}
if(!empty($my_books))
{
 foreach($my_books as $key=>$value)
 {
  unset($shop_books[$key]);
 }
}
```

Comment: А почему выборка по 10 идёт до удаления, а не после?

Comment: Посмотрите код.

Comment: Так почему "выборка по 10 идёт до удаления, а не после?" Вы не ответили на вопрос. То, что у вас так реализовано - увидели, а ответа - нет. Почему, например, нельзя сразу делать выборку без этих элементов?

Ведь вы как-то получаете $my_books. Откуда? Из БД? Может сразу построить запрос с NOT IN?

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0; $count = 0;
while ($count < 10) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `books` $sql ORDER BY `level` ASC LIMIT   ".$begin0 + $i.", 1") or die(mysql_error());
  // проверяем $result на in_array в my_books
  // увеличиваем $count на 1 если все ок
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите код.